# Undefine index while using $_POST with a select list

Tags: php, html

Could anyone tell me why am i having an "Undefined index" warning?
I don't have any clue..

```
    <?php
    function li(){
        if(isset($_POST['send'])){
            $a=$_POST['encrypt'];

        }echo $a;
    }
?>

<select name="encrypt" size="3">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

EDIT: Here is where i defined 'send'

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" name="send">
```

Here is the whole code:

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
    </br>

<form method="post">
Text</br> <textarea name="text" rows="5" columns=40></textarea></br>
</br></br>Encrypted</br> <textarea name="en" rows="5" columns="40"><?php li(); ?></textarea></br>
<input type="submit" value="Send" name="send">
</form> 
<?php
    function li(){
        if(isset($_POST['send'])){
            $a=$_POST['encrypt'];

        }echo $a;
    }
?>

<select name="encrypt" size="3">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>


    </body>
</html>
```

I have put the select into the form section but it still doesn't work.

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
    </br>

<form method="post" action="index.php">
Text</br> <textarea name="text" rows="5" columns=40></textarea></br>
</br></br>Encrypted</br> <textarea name="en" rows="5" columns="40"><?php li(); ?></textarea></br>
<input type="submit" value="Send" name="send">

<select name="encrypt" size="3">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

</form> 

<?php
    function li(){
        if(isset($_POST['send'])){
            $a=$_POST['encrypt'];

        }echo $a;
    }

    print_r($_POST);
?>



    </body>
</html>
```

LAST EDIT:
Everything is fine after the last change... I just needed to choose the option frome the list. I will need to protect it from this error :> Sorry, my bad

Comment: Where does `$_POST['send']` come from? What is the whole error message?

Comment: Here, sorry:

<input type="submit" value="Send" name="send">

Comment: I would assume `$_POST['encrypt']` isn't defined. You're testing if `$_POST['send']` is set

Comment: Are you sure `$_POST['encrypt']` is set?

Comment: Ok... so your button is named that. But why not test for the variable you're actually using?

Comment: Shouldn't it be set by <select name="encrypt">?

Comment: Can you show the rest of your form code? Maybe the <select> isn't in the right <form> (if forms are nested too it just doesn't work well at all). Also be sure the undefinied index is indeed this line

Comment: What about "Undefined index" do you not understand?

Answer (score 1):

Your SELECT tag is outside FORM.. make it inside

```
   <form method="post">
    Text</br> <textarea name="text" rows="5" columns=40></textarea></br>
    </br></br>Encrypted</br> <textarea name="en" rows="5" columns="40"><?php li(); ?></textarea></br>
    <select name="encrypt" size="3">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
   </select>
<input type="submit" value="Send" name="send">
    </form>
```

Comment: I did that but i still get the warning about the line with
$_POST['encrypt'];

Comment: try print_r($_POST) to check post elements

Comment: this is what i get:
Array ( [text] => [en] =>
Notice: Undefined index: encrypt in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 38
[send] => Send ) 

I am no pro in php and i don't understand why 'encrypt' is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep your dropdown for `encrypt` in `<form>` tag.

```
<form method="post">
Text</br> <textarea name="text" rows="5" columns=40></textarea></br>
</br></br>Encrypted</br> <textarea name="en" rows="5" columns="40"><?php li(); ?></textarea></br>
<select name="encrypt" size="3">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Send" name="send">
</form> 
<?php
    function li(){
        $a = '';
        if(isset($_POST['send']) && isset($_POST['encrypt'])){
            $a=$_POST['encrypt'];

        }echo $a;
    }
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also check condition for `$_POST['encrypt']` in function.

Comment: I've made that change in my code. I've added select to the form section but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @user3076722 Can you show me an error or else what is happening now

Answer (score 0):

This Should work.You have three things to select from and no default value to fall to in case none is selected and therefore you get that error.
And this should be your error:"PHP Notice:  Undefined index: encrypt in... "

```
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
</br>

<form method="post" action="">
Text</br> <textarea name="text" rows="5" columns=40></textarea></br>
</br></br>Encrypted</br> <textarea name="en" rows="5" columns="40"><?php li();       ?></textarea></br>
<input type="submit" value="Send" name="send">

<select name="encrypt" size="3">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>

</form> 
</body>
</html>

<?php
  function li()
{
    if(isset($_POST['send']))
    {
        if(isset($_POST['encrypt']))
        {

        $a = $_POST['encrypt'];
        }
        else { $a = 1;}

    }
    echo $a;
}

print_r($_POST);
?>
```